# How to get labeled edges with GraphSharp

Tags: c#, graph, edges

I'm an absolute beginner in C#. 
I draw some graphs with Graph# a few days ago. Now I don't know how to get labeled edges. By getting information on the internet, I saw this code:

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type graphsharp:EdgeControl}">
        <Style.Resources>
            <ToolTip x:Key="ToolTipContent">
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="txtBlock" FontWeight="Bold" Text="Kanten Information"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ID}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding AD}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </ToolTip>
        </Style.Resources>
        <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{StaticResource ToolTipContent}"/>
    </Style>
```

But I don't want to show the edge information by using ToolTip. Otherwise it should be visible by using a label which is positioned in the middle of the edge. 
I've tried it with implementing a template for the edges but it doesn't work, because the visualisation of the edges got lost.

Thanks for your help!!!